Elementor Styling Control Settings
I'm working on an elementor widget and I'm facing issue with elementor Styling Contorls. I define some default values to a styling options
like:
        // ======= *Sub-Title Styling Start Here* ======= //
        $this->start_controls_section(
            'sub-title-slider',
            [
                'tab'   => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::TAB_STYLE,
                'label' => esc_html__('Sub Title Styling', 'cafena')
            ]
        );

        // ======= *Sub-Title Typography* ======= //
        $this->add_group_control(
            \Elementor\Group_Control_Typography::get_type(),
            [
                'label' => esc_html__('Sub Title Typography', 'cafena'),
                'name' => 'sub-title_typo-slider',
                'selector' => '{{WRAPPER}} your_class',
                'fields_options' => [
                    // first mimic the click on Typography edit icon
                    'typography' => ['default' => 'yes'],
                    // then redifine the Elementor defaults
                    'font_size' => ['default' => ['size' => 20]],
                    'font_weight' => ['default' => 400],
                    'line_height' => ['default' => ['size' => 40]],
                    'font_family' => ['default' => 'Rubik',],
                ],
            ]
        );

        // ======= *Sub-Title Color* ======= //
        $this->add_control(
            'sub-title_color-slider',
            [
                'label' => esc_html__('Sub Title Color', 'cafena'),
                'type' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::COLOR,
                'selectors' => [
                    '{{WRAPPER}} your_class' => 'color: {{VALUE}} !important',
                ],
            ]
        );

        $this->end_controls_section();
        // ======= *Sub-Title Styling Start Here* ======= //

and it's output is like:
enter image description here
But when I make changes like if I change the font-style it and after that I click the reset button on the top right side then it will revert back my default setting but not values and after a while I client on styling option again it will change that font-size or font-family like i change (its default font-family from Aramanth to Amatic SC) it will not come back to the default font-family which is "Aramanth" and only change the on screen font-family not the value back to "Aramanth"
enter image description here
